# curl outfile variable not working in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl

Attempting to shorten a bash script that uses curl to fetch multiple API calls takes something like this:

```
curl --user $USER:$PASS https://api.example.com/foo -o 'foo.json'
curl --user $USER:$PASS https://api.example.com/bar -o 'bar.json'
curl --user $USER:$PASS https://api.example.com/baz -o 'baz.json'
```

And use it in this form:

```
curl --user $USER:$PASS https://api.example.com/{foo,bar,baz} -o '#1.json'
```

The issue is that curl is fetching foo, bar and baz but is not assigning the output to foo.json, bar.json and baz.json. It is literally creating #1.json and piping output to stdout. Has been tried with single, double, and no quotes, all same result. 
This is being run inside a bash script, although the curl command behaves the same way when entered directly on the command line. Is this an OS X syntax issue?

Comment: What is it you think the `#1` syntax is supposed to do? Where does that come from? Anyway you're almost certainly better off running three different `curl` invocations in a loop.

Comment: The `#1` syntax is described in the `curl` man page, if you're curious.

Comment: @larsks yes I see it how, it's part of cURL's pesky built-in globbing. Thanks for educating both myself and the OP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that the `{...}` expression is *also* valid shell syntax.  For example, run:

```
echo file/{one,two}
```

And you get:

```
file/one file/two
```

So when you run:

```
curl --user $USER:$PASS https://api.example.com/{foo,bar,baz} -o '#1.json'
```

The `{foo,bar,baz}` is getting interpreted by your *shell*, and `curl` actually receives the command line:

```
  curl --user youruser:secret https://api.example.com/foo https://api.example.com/bar https://api.example.com/baz -o '#1.json'
```

Since `curl` doesn't see the `{...}` expression, you don't get the
magical handling for `#1`.  The solution is simply to enclose the URL
in single quotes:

```
curl --user $USER:$PASS 'https://api.example.com/{foo,bar,baz}' -o '#1.json'
```

The single quotes inhibit any shell expansion of the string.

Comment: Wow, and here I was thinking this question was just based on a misunderstanding of how shell expansion works.  Well done.

Comment: Brilliant. Always a small detail that's overlooked causing confusing problems. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Amazing explanation!